# Get my IP address without 'ifconfig' or 'ip addr'?

Tags: linux, ip

I've got a stripped-down Linux container. I want to find out its IP address. I don't have `ifconfig` or `ip` installed (and I don't want to install them, since they'd just get deleted when I next rebuild the container).

Can I get the IP address from somewhere in `/proc`?